# Set input as variable to pass into a table

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have a jsp file that gets employee id input from the user. I wish to send that input into a MySQL table. How am I to do this?

```
<springForm:form method="POST" commandName="employee"
     <table>
      <tr>
          <td>Employee ID:</td>
          <td><springForm:input path="id" /></td>
          <td><springForm:errors path="id" cssClass="error" /></td>
      </tr>
      ....
      <%
       Connection con = null;
       try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila","root","2scream4");
            PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("Insert into employee(id) VALUES(?)");
...
```

Comment: You are using a framework. Why then use Scriptlets on JSPs? Display the request parameter value before parsing it to see whether that value represents a valid number that can be parsed to a desired type like `int`, `long` or another expected type.

Comment: @Tiny I'm not following/understanding what you are saying regarding scriptlets on jsps? Are you referring to my java code within a jsp?

Answer (score 0):

You an do a `int id = request.getParameter("id");` and pass that to your prepared statement.

```
  PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("Insert into table_name VALUES(?)");
stat.setInt(1, id);
```

Comment: getParameter wants a string.

Comment: no, I fixed it by `int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("employeeID"));` but then got a numberformatexception on that line so I do a try, catch, but it doesn't like `setInt(1, id) when I do that.